# How can I get the properties of an Image which is being dsiplayed in a webpage

Tags: javascript, vbscript, domdocument

When one right clicks an image in a webpage and selects "Properties", one gets a display which details the URL, Size, Dimensions, Created (date), Modified (date), etc.

Obviously I know the URL as it is in my code, but some of the others are not, for example created and modified dates, they have to be coming from the server at the image source.  I  have tried using the

```
document.getElementById("photo").attributes
```

where the related HTML code is this

```
<img id="photo" src="http://www.somesite.com/photo.jpg" width="320" height="240" alt="offline" >
```

but that only returns the 5 attributes found in the above img line.

Since the dates and other information are available for the "Properties Dialogue" I assume there are also available somewhere in the document object.

Any ideas as to how I might access them using JavaScript or VBScript?

Thanks....RDK

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try get the the URL of the image, then do an AJAX request to the image, get the response headers and they will tell you the created date, etc.. that you are after...

Example...

```
var myImageURL = %YOUR_IMAGE_URL%
var modifiedHeader = 'Last-Modified';
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('HEAD', myImageURL, false);
req.send();
var header = req.getResponseHeader(modifiedHeader);
if (header) {
    console.log(header); // this is the last modified date
}
```

EDIT:
<del>This would work only if the image was accessible via AJAX... (same-origin policy, etc...)</del>

EDIT:

Changed to head so SOP does not matter now.. Thanks @Musa

Comment: If you use a HEAD request SOP will not kick in

Comment: Musa and @Michael Coxon...Thanks for the input.  I tried using code similar to the above [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176324/determine-datelastmodified-for-a-web-base-jpg-image-via-asp-or-aspnet/20179406?iemail=1&noredirect=1#20179406 It works for some image sources but not others.  That is why I am trying it this way.

Comment: @RDK the code I provided will not work in IE. You will have to do those overrides yourself. If you try in any other browser it should work. You might need to play with the case of the `modifiedHeader` variable to get the results you want - I am not sure if JS converts the case from the server. If it does not there is a `getAllResponseHeaders` function you can use and then you can parse the array it returns.

Comment: Michael.....Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I copied your code directly, updated the url  but it fails.  It executes the req.open("HEAD", myImageURL, false);

but does not get past the req.send();

Comment: Michael.....Did not get the above edited within the 5 minutes.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I copied your code directly, updated the url  but it fails.  It executes the req.open("HEAD", myImageURL, false);

but does not get past the req.send();

Now to be perhaps more clear about the code in the above link.  It works perfectly for some URL's but seems to hang on others, ie a waiting for a readystate=4 condition.  I suspect some servers are blocking this access....RDK

Comment: Reqardless, I still interested to know if there is a way to access the data that is being displayed in the "right-click/Properties" dialogue.  Thanks....Rob

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated using the JavaScript [Image object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp)?

Comment: Mark....I looked at that object, but did not see/understand how it would apply to this issue.  Can you supply any more details or code? I'll look at it again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Information like the creation and modification dates will be stored (if anywhere) in the image's EXIF metadata.

There is a [jQuery library for reading EXIF metadata](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exifjquery/) that provides an `exif()` method, e.g. `$('img').exif('DateTimeOriginal')`.

Note that images hosted on a different domain will not be accessible to JavaScript.

Information about the width and height of the original image file should be properties of the image object itself, e.g. `document.getElementById('photo').naturalHeight`

Comment: Alf...Thanks, I'll  look this up and give it a try ...RDK